# Dapper mapped multiple relation

Tags: c#, dapper

this is my models:

```
public class Word
{
    public string Word1 { get; set; }               
    public string SpecialCases { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Defination> Definations { get; set; }
}

public class Defination
{
    public long WordId { get; set; }        
    public string Subjects { get; set; }    
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<Example> Examples { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public long DefinationId { get; set; }            
    public string English { get; set; }        

    public virtual Defination Defination { get; set; }
}
```

i want to use dapper to mapped my result to models. this is my code to use it,

```
string query = 
    $"SELECT Word.*, Defination.* " + 
    $"FROM Word Left Join Defination On Word.id = Defination.Id " +                    
    $"WHERE Word.id = {id} ";                   
    var item2 = cn.Query<Word, Defination, Word>(query,
        (Word, Defination) =>
            {                            
                Word.Definations.Add(Defination);
                Defination.Word = Word;                            
                return Word;
            }
        );
    return item2.FirstOrDefault();
```

my Problem is how to add examples data to each Defination model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my Problem from this code:

```
public Word GetByID(long id)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
            {
                cn.Open();
                const string wordQuery = "SELECT * FROM Word WHERE Id = @Id AND Word.SoftDelete = 0 ";
                Word _word = cn.Query<Word>(wordQuery, new { Id = id }).FirstOrDefault();
                if(_word != null && _word.Id != 0)
                {
                    const string definationQuery = "SELECT * FROM Defination where WordId = @WordId AND SoftDelete = 0";
                    List<Defination> _defination = cn.Query<Defination>(definationQuery, new { WordId = _word.Id }).ToList();
                    _word.Definations = _defination;
                    if(_defination != null && _defination.Any())
                    {
                        const string exampleQuery = "SELECT * FROM Example where DefinationId = @DefinationId AND SoftDelete = 0";
                        for (int i=0; i<_defination.Count(); i++ )
                        {
                            _defination[i].Examples = cn.Query<Example>(exampleQuery, new { DefinationId = _defination[i].Id }).ToList();                            
                        }                        
                    }
                }

                return _word;
            }
        }
```

i know its not clean enough but its worked for me. thanks